# R Shiny: use HTML within functions (like textInput, checkboxGroupInput)

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm trying to include HTML in a shiny `textInput()` function. More specific I want to include an image right next to text that is displayed within the widgets. The following was written in `ui.R`:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Page Title",theme = shinytheme("united"),
  tabPanel("Panel title",          
     sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(

         textInput("textInputObject", c("Input Header", tags$span(HTML("<img src='http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png', title='help', alt='' />"))), value = "put text here"),

         checkboxGroupInput("checkbInp", "Checkbox Header",
                            c("Checkbox1 [?]"           = "check1"            , 
                              "Checkbox2 [?]"           = "check2"          , 
                              "Checkbox3 [?]"           = "check3")          , 
                            selected = c("check1"))
  )
)
```

This gives me:

[image]

There are 2 Problems:

1. I was able to include the image in the header of the `textInput`. However, it should only show "Input Header" and then the image. As you see in the picture, "span" from `tags$span` is also shown. How can I solve this?
2. I have no idea how to include the image in the `checkboxGroupInput`. It is supposed to replace the "[?]" (see image)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for **#1** you can easily fix this by using `list` before the `HTML` call. For **#2** is a bit trickier as you would probably need to write the entire `checkbox` yourself. Perhaps if you could declare separate ones as I did, would that be ok?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- navbarPage("Page Title",theme = shinytheme("united"),
                 tabPanel("Panel title",          
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              textInput("textInputObject", 
                                        c("Input Header",list(HTML("<img src='http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png'/>"))), value = "put text here"),
                              checkboxInput("checkbInp",c("Checkbox1",list(HTML("<img src='http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png'/>"))), value = T),
                              checkboxInput("checkbInp2",c("Checkbox2",list(HTML("<img src='http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png'/>")))),
                              checkboxInput("checkbInp3",c("Checkbox3",list(HTML("<img src='http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png'/>"))))
                            ),
                          mainPanel())
                 )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: It's work-around, but it works fine. So far I did not come across a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If span tag is not required, just try like this:

```
textInput("textInputObject", c("Input Header", tags$img(src = "http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png", title = "help", alt = ""), value = "put text here")
```

Comment: I tried that earlier. Unfortunately it will make the resulting HTML-Page to not show the image, but
**Input Header img http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png help**

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have the chance to test it right now, but you could try `tags$span(tags$img(src = "http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png", title = "help", alt = ""))` or just `c("Input Header", "<span><img src='http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png', title='help', alt='' /></span>")`

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'm afraid, neither of the suggestions will work. First solution one will produce thes same problem as stated initially: "Input Header span" then post die image. The second solution will show the HTML tag as is: "Input Header <span><img src='http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/10/0401/Blue-question-mark-icon-1004195336.png', title='help', alt='' /></span>"